# Why wasn't Nuclear Man born naked?

Tags: dc, movie, superman, superman-4

In the movie *Superman IV: The Quest for Peace*, Lex Luthor used Superman's DNA & the fusion power of the Sun to give birth to Nuclear Man. In the movie, it was shown how the embryo grew to full size near the Sun. Assuming it was normal human biology mixed with Kryptonian super powers, why was Nuclear Man born with a costume? Interestingly, the costume was well-designed with Nuclear Man's brand logo. How was this possible?

Comment: I was always more confused by him flying Louis into space and her not dying

Comment: @Stefan http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-did-lacy-survived-in-outer-space :)

Comment: Yep, no rational solution is pretty much what I figured! (and thanks for the link!) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the computer made it possible that Nuclear man was not born naked.

In the movie, Lex Luthor cuts a piece of fabric when he created the box with genetic material and computer to be sent into the sun with a nuclear weapon. We have to suspend disbelief that with all the calculations and "science" involved, Nuclear man was created, full-grown, and with a costume after being sent into the sun.

From the movie:

> **Lex Luthor**: Now the fabric... 
>   **Lenny**: Uncle Lex, this ain't going to
>   cover him. 
>   **Lex Luthor**: The *computer* inside will leave enough material
>   to maintain the high moral standards I've always subscribed to.

The fabric can be seen on the table on the top middle left of the screenshot.

[image: The fabric is on the middle left.]

Lex cuts the fabric, before placing it into the box.

[image: Lex cuts a piece of fabric.]