# How did Lacy survive in outer space?

Tags: dc, movie, superman, superman-4

In the *Superman IV: The Quest for Peace* movie, Nuclear Man liked Lacy and kidnapped her. When Superman rescued her she was already in outer space. How did she survive? Is this something to do with super powers of Superman and Nuclear Man?

Comment: Superman has a "super-aura" that extends around him and whatever he's touching. It's the reason Lois doesn't die when he catches her; https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-05e549c07814407c458be2d23c0a7ff0-c?convert_to_webp=true. Possibly Nuclear Man has one as well and inadvertently kept her alive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way she could have survived, and there isn't any in-universe attempt to even try and explain how it happened. While Superman does display a few new abilities here (some kind of telekenesis w/ the Great Wall and the police officers), they don't explain how Lacy was able to breathe, nor how she survived in the near-zero pressure environment without protection.

Out-of-universe, this is just another example of the poor quality of this movie, which has been widely acknowledged by just about everyone who worked on it. In this case I haven't even heard of any rumored missing, deleted, or rejected elements of the story that would have explained this problem (though it's likely that a more thorough writer or director would have at least tried).